# split view controller's view does not rotate on changing the orientation of the Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am a beginner level programmer.

Can anybody tell the method using which I can enable the *SplitViewController's View to get itself vertical always* , whatever be the change in the orientation of the device.

For Your Information

1. I had already tried **shouldAutoRotate()** and

   ```
     -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
   ```

   But both didn't work, 2nd one even not getting a call.
2. I have made this programmatically with XIB's, without using the     storyboard, and also have deleted the View Controller.
3. With using Master-Detail Template its working, but programmatically, only the rotation of the view thing is not working, other things are smoothly working
4. I have also taken the custom split view controller.
5. Besides this I have tried without taking the Custom SplitViewController. But it still didn't work.

Is there any other way to do this without using the master-detail template???

Comment: there r some viewController which can rotate other are not???

Comment: the parent and child view controllers , both doesn't rotate, only the status bar get rotated.